# RPM from installed package

Tags: rpm, packages, export

The question is simple. I have an old CentOS 7 system that has some installed packages with specific version numbers. However, these versions are unavailable now in the repository they were downloaded from (namely php and about 20 php modules) I want to export the installed packages into rpms so I can install them on another server. Any idea how to?

I've tried already `rpm -aq | grep php | xargs -L1 rpmrebuild -br`, but this resulted in a lot of errors and was able to export about half of the packages. The rest was coming back with an error message: `warning: Explicit %attr() mode not applicaple to symlink: /root/.tmp/rpmrebuild.18231/my_root/usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/autoload.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems quite suicidal... Consider one of the following alternatives:

- search those exact packages online (http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3 or similar)
- upgrade those packages; mostly those are bugfixes that you probably want to install

Comment: Thanks, I did that. I mean the searching for each individual package. I just finished since posting the question. :( It is unfortunate, but I'm not allowed to update because the project has a very special custom made PHP extension that is bind to a specific PHP version.